# Limits and Derivatives Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Define functions $f_n$ on $R$ by
$$f_n(x)=\sqrt {x^2+\frac{1}{n}}$$.
Show Show that each $f_n$ is differentiable and find its derivative.
I am beginning to approach this problem by using the definition of differentiable to show that the function is differentiable everywhere. However, this seem to be a bit difficult and I am not quite sure it is correct. What is the best approach to begin this?

Comment: What is required is context dependent. This is probably the first part of a multipart question, about the limit of $f_n'(x)$ as $n\to infity$, and the derivative of the limit function. So for this you are probably just expected to differentiate, one short line.

Answer (score 1):

Each $\,f_n(x)\,$ is defined everywhere and it is the composition of differentiable functions and thus differentiable itself:

$$\frac{d(f_n(x))}{dx}=f'_n(x)=\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+\frac1n}}$$

Further explanation: we have in fac that

$$f_n=g\circ h\;,\;\;h(x)=x^2+\frac1n\;,\;\;g(x):=\sqrt x$$

so applying the chain rule:

$$f_n'(x)=(g\circ h)'(x)=g'(h(x))\cdot h'(x)=\frac1{2\sqrt{h(x)}}\cdot2x=\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+\frac1n}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the facts that (a) $x^2$ is differentiable, (b) $x^2$ is non-negative on $\mathbb{R}$ (so that $x^2 + 1/n$ is always strictly positive), (c) the chain rule gives that the composition of differentiable functions is differentiable, and (d) $\sqrt{x}$ is differentiable away from zero.

That is a high-level strategy. Without knowing how much of this you can assume or prove easily, I can't really say more than this.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$. If I understand correctly you are using the definition differentiability to demonstrate differentiability of the functions $f_{n}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

$\frac{f_{n}(x+h)-f_{n}(x)}{h}=\frac{\sqrt{(x+h)^{2}+\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt{x^{2}+\frac{1}{n}}}{h}=\frac{\bigg((x+h)^{2}+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)-\bigg(x^{2}+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)}{h\big(\sqrt{(x+h)^{2}+\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{x^{2}+\frac{1}{n}}\big)}=\frac{\bigg(x^{2}+2xh+h^{2}+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)-\bigg(x^{2}+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)}{h\big(\sqrt{(x+h)^{2}+\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{x^{2}+\frac{1}{n}}\big)}$

$=\frac{2x+h}{\sqrt{(x+h)^{2}+\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{x^{2}+\frac{1}{n}}}$.

Letting $h$ go to $0$ and using continuity of $x$, $\sqrt{x}$, and $x^{2}$ gives $\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^{2}+\frac{1}{n}}}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+\frac{1}{n}}}$ which is the derivative. No assumptions were made in terms of $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$ so this proof holds for all natural numbers $n$ and real numbers $x$.

You can proceed quicker by applying chain rule and standard differentiation rules.